# How to keep focus at current range when switching from input to textarea in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form as an `input` but when the number of characters exceeds 50, then it switch to a `textarea`. I first had troubles with the focus, as it was lost when switching from one to the other, but by adding the tag `autofocus` fixed.
However, I still have the issue that the cursor doesn't keep track of the range. Basically, when the form switch from `input` to `textarea`, the cursor goes back to the start of the form. I fixed it by adding:

```
onFocus={e => e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(e.currentTarget.value.length, e.currentTarget.value.length)}
```

With this, the cursor always goes to the end of the form, which is fine 90% of the time.
However, if the user points the cursor at the beginning or middle of the form, and the form switches at this moment, then the cursor is pushed to the end of the line again which is an issue.

Is there any way to keep the cursor at the same place when the forms are switching?

Comment: Sharing a stackblitz or codesandbox would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How about using them attibutes such as maxLength/minLength/pattern. There is an event which fires right after the element looses focus: onBlur

```
<input onBlur={e=>{
 const {target} = e;

 if (target.value !== “yow condition”) {
  e.preventDefault();

  target.focus();

   return;

}
/// if value is good continue normal flow
}}/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when my form switches from <input/> to <textarea/>, onBlur is not called at all...